# Notepad++ changes the encoding of my code

Tags: python, notepad++

I've some python code, that contains recognition for some hindi text. I deliberately save it as `UTF-8`, but when I re-open it, the hindi symbols change to russian text(mostly) or simply a `?`. The encoding too changes to `OEM 866` which is cyrillic.

Here are the screenshots, (lines 90 and 98):
[image]
[image]

Because of this encoding change, my code too isn't running at all, as the regular expressions consider `?` as a special input. So what should I do?

Comment: For precisely reasons like this, I would suggest keeping your Python files in ASCII plaintext and using Unicode codepoints to capture the symbols instead. I.e. `\u0905\u092d\u0940` == अभी

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encoding the script to `utf-8-BOM` would do the job. But `BOM` itself has [problems of it's own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38038099/5345646). Basically, if you're using shebangs, then using BOM encoding would render the script uninterpretable.

---

**EDIT:** A notepad++ contributor on github [rddim](https://github.com/rddim) replied to the [issue opened by me](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/4612):

> I can't reproduce this, because may be I have missed fonts. On 1st
>   screen your file is in `UTF-8` and the 2nd is in `OEM-866`. **Check the
>   state of Autodetect character encoding in `Settings > Preferences... > MISC..` If it is enabled just disable it and try again.** Also your Debug
>   Information missed the info from ? > Debug Info...

Worked for me.